# Hive LLAP low Vcore allocation

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn

**Problem Statment:**

Hive LLAP Daemons not consuming Cluster VCPU allocation. 80-100 cores available for LLAP daemon, but only using 16.

**Summary:**

I am testing Hive LLAP on Azure using 2 D14_v2 head nodes, 16 D14_V2 Worker Nodes, and 3 A series Zookeeper nodes. (D14_V2 = 112GB Ram/12vcpu)

The 15 nodes of the 16 node Cluster is dedicated to LLAP

The Distribution is HDP 2.6.3.2-14

Currently the cluster has a total of 1.56TB of Ram Available and 128vcpu. The LLAP Daemons are allocated the proper amount of memory, but the LLAP Daemons only uses 16vcpus total ( 1 vcpu per daemon + 1 vcpu for slider).

**Configuration:**

My relevant hive configs are as follows:

- hive.llap.daemon.num.executors = 10 (10 of the 12 available vcpu per
  node)
- Yarn Max Vcores per container - 8

**Other:**

I have been load testing the cluster but unable to get any more vcpus engaged in the process. Any thoughts or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Manager UI will only show you query co-ordinator and slider's core and memory allocation, each query co-ordinator in LLAP occupy 1 core and mininum alloted Tez-AM memory (tez.am.resource.memory.mb). To check realtime core usage by LLAP service for HDP 2.6.3 version, follow below steps:

> Ambari -> Hive -> Quick Links -> Grafana -> Hive LLAP overview ->
>   Total Execution Slots